# unable to read data from sqlitedabse in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to use a existing sqlite database in my application and and put my database file (that I created by Db browser for sqlite portable software in windows 7 OS)in assets folder of android studio, I write a databaseOpenHelper class like this :

```
package com.example.javad.dbproject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class myDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.javad.dbproject/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "database1.sqlite";
public static final String TB_USER = "dataSheet";

private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private final Context context;

//constructor
public myDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //Handle creation tasks, etc.
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //Handle upgrade tasks, etc.
}
    @Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDB != null)
        myDB.close();
    super.close();
}
//Check if our database already exists
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}
/***
 * Copy database from source code assets to device
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}
/***
 * Open database
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
/***
 * Check if the database doesn't exist on device, create new one
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getAllUsers(){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
        if(c == null) return null;

        String name;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            name = c.getString(1);
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();

    return listUsers;
}
```

and I modified main activity java file in this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
myDatabaseHelper dbHeplper;
ListView lvUsers;
ListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHeplper = new myDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        dbHeplper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    List<String> listUsers = dbHeplper.getAllUsers();

    if (listUsers != null) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                listUsers);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

But when I run this app,list view does not return any value from my database and this message appears in logcat:"error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)" and "E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: dataSheet"

It seeems that Android studio can not locate or read information from my database file,Any Ideas welcome!

here is logcat message after running app:
http://textuploader.com/p9zt

Comment: can you please post your stacktrace?

Comment: Do you mean logcat messages?

Comment: Yes please, it would be better to see it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> First of all we need to create a folder for databases folder then copy
>   databaseFile then it works fine.

```
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        File dbFile=new dbFile(DB_PATH);
        dbFile.mkdirs();

        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, But I think the true form should be:                       File dbFile=new File(DB_PATH);Is this true?Anyway this trick can not solve my problem and logcat messages do not change.

Comment: once uninistall and reinstall the app and check. sometimes empty database is created due to errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that kinda experience like that. To solve that issue,

> - check "databases" folder is existed or not first. If not existed, create "databases" folder first.
> - If "databases" folder is existed, then call "copyDataBase" function.

**Sometimes, "databases" folder is missing in earlier android version.**

Comment: Thank for you attention,I created a assets folder (right click on res,then select New,select Folder and finally select Assets folder) in android studio and put my database file on that,is this wrong? Where I should put my database file?

Comment: nope. You want to copy database from your asset folder to your app core data's databases folder, am I right? If then, to write coding as I mention.

Comment: I created a databases folder in main folder of app,but nothing changed,Can You tell me what is your meaning about " then call "copyDataBase" function"

Comment: Can you check first while calling "copyDataBase()", it's successfully done or got "Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());" from Logcat ?

Comment: See @Krishna V's answer. He got the point and copy my answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,I applied code provided by Krishna V,But my problem was not resolved!